# How to fix my terminal prompt being out by a character?

Tags: terminal

My terminal prompt is set using the following configuration in my `.profile` file:

```
# Prompt
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
LIME_YELLOW=$(tput setaf 190)
MAGENTA=$(tput setaf 5)
WHITE=$(tput setaf 7)
NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)
PS1="\[${WHITE}${MAGENTA}\]\u\[${WHITE}@${GREEN}\]\h \[${LIME_YELLOW}\]\W \[${WHITE}${NORMAL}\]$ "
```

Generally speaking it works fine but sometimes I end up with an off-by-one error. After a running a few commands and then accessing the history using the `up` key, some characters seem to be getting garbled. For example:

```
matt@laptop ~ $ git log
```

becomes

```
matt@laptop ~ $ gitlog
```

or:

```
matt@laptop ~ $ ssh desktop
```

becomes

```
matt@laptop ~ $ssh desktop
```

The incorrectly displayed command executes normally and appears in history normally too.

Comment: Only the color sequences should be surrounded by `\[` and `\]` markers. The `@` should be outside of the markers.

Comment: That seems to have done it. I'll mark it as correct if you post it as a fully fledged answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\[` and `\]` markers are used to surround text that, when displayed on the screen, will take up zero width, such as control sequences that set colors. The `@` and any other ordinary text should be outside of the markers.

So instead of

```
PS1="\[${WHITE}${MAGENTA}\]\u\[${WHITE}@${GREEN}\]\h \[${LIME_YELLOW}\]\W \[${WHITE}${NORMAL}\]$ "
```

use this

```
PS1="\[${WHITE}${MAGENTA}\]\u\[${WHITE}\]@\[${GREEN}\]\h \[${LIME_YELLOW}\]\W \[${WHITE}${NORMAL}\]$ "
```

More info at [Bash FAQ 053](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053).